# How can I convert a date to YYYY-MM format so I can do SUMIFS?

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I have spent hours searching for this online but I don't know why I can't find the correct answer. I have a dozens of rows in column G with dates like 6/6/2019 or 2/1/2020. I am trying to get all of them in the format YYYY-MM on another column E and then do SUMIFS based on that column. The SUMIFS will be looking for the criteria YYYY-MM and adding other columns.

Using Row 14 as an example, I used this formula on Column E: **TEXT(G14,"YYYY-MM")**

The result of **2019-06** on cell E14 LOOKS like how it's supposed to look like but something is wrong with the formatting. The SUMIFS return 0. If I search column E for 2019-06, Excel doesn't find anything even though I see multiple cells with that value. The only way the SUMIFS work if I copy and paste col E as values which is less than ideal.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the sumifs formula?

Comment: The problem is not with your `TEXT` formula it is with the `SUMIFS` and unless you show your formula, we cannot help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
=TEXT(date,"yyyymm")
```

Likewise, if you want to convert date to text, use:

```
=TEXT(date,format)
```